# echo UPLOADPATH . $row['image'] not echoing filename

Tags: php, echo

I am confused why this would not be echoing the following content? I'm guessing I've written something wrong, but **all** of the other echo's in this page are working fine.

The selected $row content from 'image' column:

```
test.png
```

The IMG_UPLOADPATH:

```
../media/images/dynamic/
```

The code:

```
<?php echo '<img src="'. IMG_UPLOADPATH . $row['image'] .'" alt="promo image"/>';?>
```

The html result:

```
<img src="../media/images/dynamic/" alt="promo image" />;
```

Comment: what is IMG_UPLOADPATH here.  i think IMG_UPLOADPATH causimg the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like

```
$row['image']
```

is empty or does not exists